# Change number div on click

Tags: javascript, html

I necessarily need your help. To the whole of my div at the click the number from 0 must become 1, and if I reclick over it must return to 0. It must alternate between 0 & 1. But by default there must be 0. HELP!

DIV:

```
<div id="playstop">0</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried? This is extremely simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function toggle(div){
 div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML=="0" ? 1 : 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="playstop" onclick="toggle(this)">0</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try this with vanilla javascript

```html
<div id="playstop" onclick="this.innerHTML=  this.innerHTML=='0' ? '1' : '0'">0</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#playstop").on("click", function () {
    this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML=="0" ? "1" : "0";
});
```

Don't forget to reference jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Pure vanilla solution, no jQuery

```
const elem = document.getElementById("playstop");
elem.addEventListener("click", () => { 
  elem.innerText =  elem.innerText === "0" ? "1" : "0"
});
```